# Props defined by async function by Parent in UseEffect passed to a child component don't persist during its UseEffect's clean-up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please consider the following code:

Parent:

```
const Messages = (props) => {
  const [targetUserId, setTargetUserId] = useState(null);
  const [currentChat, setCurrentChat] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { userId } = props;

    const initiateChat = async (targetUser) => {
      const chatroom = `${
        userId < targetUser
          ? `${userId}_${targetUser}`
          : `${targetUser}_${userId}`
      }`;
      const chatsRef = doc(database, 'chats', chatroom);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(chatsRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setCurrentChat(chatroom);
      } else {
        await setDoc(chatsRef, { empty: true });
      }
    };
    if (props.location.targetUser) {
      initiateChat(props.location.targetUser.userId);
      setTargetUserId(props.location.targetUser.userId);
    }
  }, [props]);

  return (
...
      <Chat currentChat={currentChat} />
...
  );
};
```

Child:

```
const Chat = (props) => {

const {currentChat} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeFromChat = () => {
      try {
        onSnapshot(
          collection(database, 'chats', currentChat, 'messages'),
          (snapshot) => {
            // ... //
          }
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    return () => {
      unsubscribeFromChat();
    };
  }, []);
...
```

The issue I'm dealing with is that Child's UseEffect clean up function, which depends on the `chatroom` prop passed from its parent, throws a TypeError error because apparently `chatroom` is null. Namely, it becomes null when the parent component unmounts, the component works just fine while it's mounted and props are recognized properly.

I've tried different approaches to fix this. The only way I could make this work if when I moved child component's useEffect into the parent component and defined currentChat using `useRef()` which honestly isn't ideal.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't useEffect clean-up function depend on previous state? Is there a proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentChat` is a dependency of that effect. If it's null, the the `unsubscribe` should just early return.

```
const {currentChat} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeFromChat = () => {
      if(!currentChat) return;
      try {
        onSnapshot(
          collection(database, 'chats', currentChat, 'messages'),
          (snapshot) => {
            // ... //
          }
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    return () => {
      unsubscribeFromChat();
    };
  }, [currentChat]);
```

But that doesn't smell like the best solution. I think you should handle all the subscribing/unsubscribing in the same component. You shouldn't subscribe in the parent and then unsubscribe in the child.

EDIT:

Ah, there's a bunch of stuff going on here that's not good. You've got your userId coming in from props - props.location.targetUser.userId and then you're setting it as state. It's **NOT** state, it's only a prop. State is something a component owns, some data that a component has created, some data that emanates from that component, that component is it's source of truth (you get the idea). If your component didn't create it (like userId which is coming in on props via the `location.targetUser` object) then it's not state. Trying to keep the prop in sync with state and worry about all the edge cases is a fruitless exercise. It's just not state.

Also, it's a codesmell to have `[props]` as a dependency of an effect. You should split out the pieces of props that that effect actually needs to detect changes in and put them in the dependency array individually.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out Adam, I really appreciate it. I should've clarified where child's components useEffect comes from. It's Firebase listener. It looks like magic to me but I followed the official docs to set it up and the listener works by declaring it and returns a function to unsubscribe, hence it's called unsubscribeFromChat(). This listener is not declared in the parent component. Parent component determines whether a chat exists, if not, creates it and passes the chatroom name to Child component which subscribes to new messages, that was my idea

Comment: Your suggestion is something I implemented but I was afraid that including this safeguard clause would mask the problem - if the currentChat is null, the unsubscribe function won't work because it's needed to determine at which place a listener is to be removed. So in my testing I made sure that currentChat was not null. This would result in a memory leak. Unfortunately Firebase doesn't provide a way to check whether the listener is actually removed

Comment: @grubsztyl when doing react the wrong way, things appear hard and difficult and complicated. When doing react the right way, things appear so simple they're trivial. You're just not doing things the right way here. Take it one step at a time. First step, get rid of the `targetUserId` state.

Comment: your advices were invaluable. I got rid of the `targetUserId` state, this resulted in one unnecessary render less. Second, I included the guard clause for the currentChat. Third, I fixed the dependency arrays to be more precise. Finally, fourth.. the main issue was my lack of understanding of Firebase methods. Try and catch are unnecessary, the snapshot listener is not an async function. I also tried wrapping it in an arrow function which would break the function. I was able to verify with console.logs that, after fixing the useEffect, the listener attaches and detaches properly